# Android Google Maps: Disable Scroll on Zoom

Tags: android, scroll, maps, zooming, pinch

I tried by creating custom class for mapview but it is not working. Can any one suggest me an approach. How to disable scroll when user tries to zoom. Scroll should be enable when zoom is not performed.

Answer (score 0):

I Have solved the problem using below code.

Create variables in Class

```
private ScaleGestureDetector gestureDetector;
private long lastZoomTime = 0;
private float lastSpan = -1;
private long firstClick=0;
private long lastClick;
GoogleMap mMap;
```

In OnMapReady method add below code:

```
mMap = googleMap;
gestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), new ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            Log.i("onScale ", " onScale ");
            if (lastSpan == -1) {
                lastSpan = detector.getCurrentSpan();
            }
            if (detector.getEventTime() - lastZoomTime >= 50) {
                lastZoomTime = detector.getEventTime();
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(getZoomValue(detector.getCurrentSpan(), lastSpan)), 50, null);
                lastSpan = detector.getCurrentSpan();
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            lastSpan = -1;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            lastSpan = -1;

        }


    });
```

Add Below Methods in class

```
private float getZoomValue(float currentSpan, float lastSpan) {
    Log.i("ongetZoomValue ", " getZoomValue ");
    double value = (Math.log(currentSpan / lastSpan) / Math.log(1.55d));
    return (float) value;
}

public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    //Log.i("on dispatchTouchEvent ", " dispatchTouchEvent ");
    switch (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {




        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            fingers = fingers + 1;

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

            fingers = fingers - 1;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            fingers = 0;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


            if (firstClick != 0 && System.currentTimeMillis() - firstClick > 300) {
                Log.i("on count=0", " count=0 ");
                count = 0;
            }
            count++;
            if (count == 1) {
                Log.i("on count ", " count=1 ");
                firstClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
            } else if (count == 2) {
                Log.i("on count ", " count=2 ");
                lastClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if (lastClick - firstClick < 300) {

                    CameraUpdate getzoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn();
                    mMap.animateCamera(getzoom, 400, null);
                    Log.i("on double click ", " event ");
                }

            }


            fingers=1;
            break;
    }

    if (fingers >1) {

        //Log.i("2fingersaction ", "2fingersaction ");
        mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
        //mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);         // disableScrolling()
    }
    else if (fingers < 1 )
    {
        //Log.i("onefinger ", "onefinger ");

        mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
        // enableScrolling();
    }
    if (fingers > 1) {

        //Log.i("double if condition ", "doubleifcondition ");


        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

    } else

        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);

}
```